# Is it possible to set Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis stream format as in SAPI 5.3?

Tags: c++-winrt, speech-synthesis, sapi, system.windows.media

I'm using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis (C++/WinRT) to convert text to audio file. Previously I was using SAPI where was possible to set Audio Format when binding to a file via SPBindToFile(...) before speaking.

Is there any similar method in Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis? Seems that there is only possible to get 16kHz, 16Bit, Mono wave stream, does it?

Does SpeechSynthesisStream already contain a real audio stream after speech synthesis, or does it hold some precalculated raw data, and does actual encoding happen when accessing its data (playback on a device or copying to another not-speech-specific stream)?

Thank you!

I think there should be possible to control the speech synthesis stream format somehow.

Comment: Could you please tell me what kind of Audio Format you want to get?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, any of the available WAV formats different from the default SpeechSynthesisStream format. I know that I could transcode SpeechSynthesisStream to other audio formats later via MediaTranscoder, but I'm trying to figure out if is it possible to predefine audio format like in SAPI SPBindToFile

Comment: This is not available from `Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis`. I'm investigating if it's available via other APIs.

Answer (score 1):

The WinRT synthesis engines output 16Khz 16-bit mono data.  There isn't any resampling layer to change the format.